# Core Data: find entities filtered by attribute with unique second attribute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity `Detail` with two attributes: `title` and `text`. There are many of those, and many are duplicated, because they are assigned to many instances of another entity as a relationship.

I need all unique `text`s for a given `title`. So first I create an appropriate predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
   @"title = %@", aTitle];
```

How do I reduce the resulting results array to one with only unique `text` entries?

Can I somehow still use my `fetchedResultsController` to display these in a table view, or do I have to create a separate array as the datasource? I fear that I could run into memory troubles like this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 'NSSet * uniqueStates = [NSSet setWithArray:yourArray];'

Comment: That would not work. The members of the array are all unique, just the `text` field isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this may work with valueForKeypath:

```
    NSDictionary * dict00 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"hat" forKey:@"key"];
    NSDictionary * dict01 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"bag" forKey:@"key"];
    NSDictionary * dict02 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"shirt" forKey:@"key"];
    NSDictionary * dict03 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"hat" forKey:@"key"];
    NSDictionary * dict04 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"hat" forKey:@"key"];

    NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
    [array addObject:dict00];
    [array addObject:dict01];
    [array addObject:dict02];
    [array addObject:dict03];
    [array addObject:dict04];

    NSArray * deDupedArray = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.key"];
    NSLog(@"%@",deDupedArray);
```

Comment: outputs: (
    bag,
    shirt,
    hat
)

Comment: Thanks for this idea. As the dictionaries are actually objects with different attributes, this might get unexpected results.

Comment: how so? "The @distinctUnionOfObjects operator returns an array containing the distinct objects in the property specified by the key path to the right of the operator.

"

Comment: I did try, it does not work. Error: 'the entity ... is not key value coding-compliant for the key "distinctUnionOfObjects".'.

Comment: Using `NSDictionary`s it returns null values. I verified the dictionaries were not empty.

Comment: are you using your own key like \@distinctUnionOfObjects.dog, or \@distinctUnionOfObjects.fish if you are looking for the objects stored with the key @"dog" or @"fish"?

Comment: the at sign is important too... see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html